# Reading ReST body into Java using BufferedReader

Tags: java, rest, post, jakarta-ee, postman

I'm trying to read a ReST body into Java, from a POST request. Common advice seems to be to use request.getReader(), but it doesn't seem to be working as expected. When I go into debug and step through the code, all values are 'null', which seems to suggest it isn't reading in the payload.

I'm using Postman to send the POST request. I have body set to x-www-form-urlencoded and I'm passing a key value pair, with the json / xml object body in the value.

***NOTE.*** My web service is expected to handle both parameters and body, which is why I have an opening 'if' statement.

I've attached my code. Can anyone help?

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

  if (request.getParameter("film") == null ||
                request.getParameter("film").isEmpty()) {

     String body = "";
     StringBuilder payloadString = new StringBuilder();
     BufferedReader bufferedReader = request.getReader();

     while (bufferedReader.readLine() != null) {
        payloadString.append(line);
     }
            
     body = payloadString.toString();

     // do stuff with body

  }
}
```

Comment: I have a feeling that, if you call `request.getParameter()` the container will parse the request body into the parameters key-value structure and it will no longer be available for reading through `request.getReader()`. Can you try sending the same request with body from Postman, but comment out the `request.getParameter()` stuff to test?

Comment: thanks for the reply @NikosParaskevopoulos. i tried that, but get the same result. interestingly, when i pass the content in as raw rather than body, it reads in